# NoReverseMatch at /login/ Reverse for 'password_reset' not found. 'password_reset' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I'm having trouble with the login page for my django project.
Everything works perfectly fine with localhost but after deploying and going live it has this password_reset error.

I have googled for 3-4 hours now but I do not have a solution for this error.

It works perfectly fine on localhost but not live.
You can see it on roasitas.com/login/ if you want to see the problem

P.S: I have set to `DEBUG = False`, the error message still appeared

Why?

Thanks everyone!
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wocg6.png)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',include('news.urls', namespace="news")),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('register/', users_view.register, name='register'),
path('profile/', users_view.profile, name='profile'),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
path('password-reset/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset.html',
        subject_template_name='users/password_reset_subject.txt',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
     ),
     name='password_reset'),

path('password-reset/done/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
         template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_done'),

path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
    ),
name='password_reset_confirm'),

 path('password-reset-complete/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
         template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_complete'),


# path('web/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),

path('api/', include(router.urls)),
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
path('/tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

] 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: When you set `DEBUG = False` you should not see this error (at least not in the browser). Have you maybe deployed an old version? What happens when you set `DEBUG = False`, restart the server and then try the same page again?

Comment: the same after i did sudo systemctl restart nginx. 
You got any clue about password_reset problem  as well?